# Convert Excel formula into R code which uses previous row result

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, data.table

I have an example calculation in Excel, which i need to convert into R code for a much larger data set.

My data should look like this:

```
time value  cum_value  floor scaled_time
0    0      0          0     0
1    1      1          1     1
2    0.975  1.975      1     1
3    0.95   2.925      3     2.038961039
4    0.925  3.85       4     3.098982099
5    0.9    4.75       5     4.185278042
6    0.875  5.625      6     5.302030016
7    0.85   6.475      7     6.453196107
```

Where the 'scaled time' column has been calculated in Excel using this type of formula (example shown is for row 6):

```
=scaled_time5+((floor6-floor5)/((cum_value6-floor5)/(time6-scaled_time5)))
```

Since this refers to cells in previous rows, i am having trouble coding this in R.

This is what i have so far (using `data.table` `shift` function:

```
  DF$Scaled_Time=shift(DF$Scaled_Time, 1L, "lag")+
    ((DF$Floor-shift(DF$Floor,1L,"lag"))/
       ((DF$Cum_Value-shift(DF$Floor,1L,"lag"))/
          (DF$Time-shift(DF$Scaled_Time, 1L, "lag"))))
```

This doesn't work, and comes up with this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Scaled_Time", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, DF has 2246400
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In shift(DF$Floor, 1L, "lag") : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In shift(DF$Floor, 1L, "lag") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Shouldn't `cum_value[3]` be `2.925`? And all the following less by `1`?

Comment: Yes you're right - I didn't copy the data column correctly. I'll amend now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `shift` function from `data.table`.

```
df$result = 2.038961
df[, result := shift(result)+((floor-shift(floor))/((cum_value-shift(floor))/(time-shift(result)))) ]
```

Comment: This does not work since the `shift(result)` value is always taken to be 2.038961, and does not update with the rows. Hence, the results i get using this method are: `NA 3.098982 3.730983 4.476523 5.402377` and not `2.038961 3.098982 4.185278 5.302030 6.453196`.

Answer (score 1):

using dplyr you can get previous value by lag:

```
library(dplyr)
```

I recreated the dataframe:

```
vv <- data.frame(time=c(3,4,5,6,7),
             value=c(0.95,0.925,0.9,0.875,0.85),
             cum_value=c(3.925,4.85,5.75,6.625,7.475),
             floor=c(3,4,5,6,7),
             scaled_time=c(2.038961039,3.098982099,4.185278042,5.302030016,6.453196107))
```

<strike>Here is a simple calculation, you can use yours instead:</strike>

**time+((floor value- previous floor value)/(cum_value-previous floor value))**
will be written as:

```
> vv %>% mutate(V4=time+((floor-lag(floor,1))/(cum_value-lag(floor,1))))
  time value cum_value floor scaled_time       V4
1    3 0.950     3.925     3    2.038961       NA
2    4 0.925     4.850     4    3.098982 4.540541
3    5 0.900     5.750     5    4.185278 5.571429
4    6 0.875     6.625     6    5.302030 6.615385
5    7 0.850     7.475     7    6.453196 7.677966
```

If I didn't miss any parentheses in your original formula, it should be like that:

```
vv %>%  mutate(V=lag(scaled_time,1)+
                       ((floor-lag(floor,1))/
                                ((cum_value-lag(floor,1))/(time-lag(scaled_time,1)))
                        )
               )
```

However, it turns out that scaled_time should be the output, and the first row will be initialized with 0 (not calculated). So one of the options is for loop.

**EDIT: For Loop Solution**

Although go for loops as a last option, this is a quick solution in case of small dataframes:

```
vv$scaled_time <- 0

for (i in 2: nrow(vv))
{
 vv$scaled_time[i]= vv$scaled_time[i-1]+
                ((vv$floor[i]-vv$floor[i-1])/((vv$cum_value[i]-vv$floor[i-1])/(vv$time[i]-vv$scaled_time[i-1])))

}
```

Comment: In neither of these examples do you use a previous value from the column `V` or `V4`, which is what my formula needs to use. The `scaled_time` column i have, is the result i am looking for. In your final code example, the end would need to be `(time-lag(V,1))` which doesn't work (unless i am missing something).

Comment: @sym246 If I am not missing sth, the formula for V gives the same values u want in scaled_time, so it calculates scales_time as desired.

Comment: Yes, but you are using the `scaled_time` column to achieve this. This was an example of the output, and so it cannot be used to obtain it. In my data set, i do not have a `scaled_time` column, and need to get it using only the first 4 columns.

Comment: @sym246 So what about the 1st row? scaled_time1?

Comment: The first row will always be 0, but since i have only given the example from rows 3-7 it isn't shown. The start of the data has now been added to the Q.

Comment: Thank you @OmaymaS